# Make JSONObject Serializable

Tags: java, session, grails, serialization, deserialization

`JSONObject` class of package `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json` does not implement `Serializable`.

I want to make this object serializable as I am using session replication among application servers and `JSONObject` gets saved in session.

I have two options to achieve this:

1. Subclass `JSONObject`s that implements `Serializable`.
2. use `toString()` method on `JSONObject` object while saving this object in session.

Can anyone please suggest which one of two options should I use and what is the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [`toString`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29) method is what's intended to be used here.  That method already returns the JSON text of the object, which is suitable for transmitting or storing.

Comment: Using toString() while saving object in session is fine, but when I get that object back from the session, I have will get the String, then I need to construct JSONObject from the String.

Comment: @user1180463 Right, you can use the `JSONObject(java.lang.String string)` constructor to do that.  I don't know if this would have any more or less performance impact over serializing/deserializing objects.  Either method would have some object creation overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to serialize JSON, it is already in a store-able form(sort of the whole point of JSON). Grails has JSON parsers and "slurpers" all ready to use for you. So just store the JSON data as a string and use a parser on it to read it back out of the file.